# Inefficient LINQ Foreach Statement Times out

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

I have an issue where when looping through my foreach statement, my application returns a timeout error. Please note I cannot modify or make a view on table that I'm querying.

```
IEnumerable<MyTable> TContextData;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id)
    || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
    || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cell)
    )
{
    TContextData = (from e in db.mytable
                    where (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.id))
                    select e);
}
else
{
    TContextData = null;
}

List<EachC> mDatalist = new List<EachC>();

if (TContextData != null)
{
    foreach (var i in TContextData.ToList())
    {
        EachMR EachM = new EachMR();

        EachM.Feature = i.TRuid;
        EachM.Feature2 = i.TRuid2;
        EachM.Feature3 = i.TRuid3;
        EachM.Date = GetInnerTextfromXML(EachM.Feature3, "/Sections/Multiple/Functions/Group/Date");
        mdatalist.Add(EachM);
    }
}
```

There are around 40K rows to iterate. Is there a way I can make this more efficient?

> Error Message: An exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code

I had increased timeout in Context to

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 0;
```

but to no avail as it is just masking issue.

Comment: Do you need the entire content of a `mytable` row? Does every single row really need to be affected by "do stuff"? Can `e.id` ever be null, or just empty, or does it really need both checks? Is it any different if you `.ToList()` the second query before you start iterating? Are you needing to save changes back to the database? Are you accessing child tables of `mytable` in "do stuff" (watch for queries executing lazily in the `for` loop)? Have you profiled this to see what SQL is running? Chances are you are doing 40,000 queries instead of 1.

Comment: Why the `.Take(1)` would prevent timeouts in your `foreach` ? - I mean, obviously it will returns only one row, but why would you get ONE row instead of doing a empty (or null) check ?

Comment: How is your application hosted, how long does it take to time out? Also, your problem might not be with the linq you've shown, but with the `#Do Stuff` piece you haven't shown us. You need to profile your code, especially the #Do Stuff part, and see what part is taking too long

Comment: Your two queries as the same thing. Check to see if you have `MultipleResultSets` enabled in your connection string, in the event that the deferred execution is tripping you up. Try a .ToList() and pull the 40k records into memory to avoid that. Limit what you're bringing in if that's too much data.

Comment: What is the full error message? Wrap it in a Try/Catch and call `ToString()` on the exception and give us the full exception.

Comment: Can you try it without the call to `ToList` on the `IEnumerable`?  `ToList` will cause the entire result set to be pulled into memory.  Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but I think not calling `ToList` will make the query behave like a firehose and process the rows as it enumerates.  I don't know if that will prevent the OOM exception, though.

Comment: You check `string.IsNullOrEmpty(id)`, but also for `name` and `cell`. Why?

Comment: What kind of data is stored in your `TRuid` properties ? and what is doing the `GetInnerTextfromXML` method ? could you provide a more complete stacktrace ?

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `.ToList()` could help. Your code unnecessarily buffers all of what the query returns in a list, then iterates over that list. Just loop over `TContextData`.

Answer (score -1):

Without the exact message, it's hard to tell from where the timeout is coming; but I'll guess it's not a SQL timeout.

What your code is actually doing is executing a query against the database for each row you are trying to retrieve in your `foreach` - I mean you are probably executing 40 000 queries. Instead, you should load your data into memory and execute your code on the list with the `.ToList()` method, which will execute the query once.

```
IEnumerable TContextData;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(id)
|| !string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
|| !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cell))
{
    TContextData = (from e in db.mytable where (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.id)) select e); 
}

foreach(var i in TContextData.ToList())
{    
    //do stuff
}
```

Again, I'm talking without having all the context; the answer would be a bit different if you are using `EF`, `LinqToSQL`, or a `DataReader` converted to an `IEnumerable`...

Comment: That's not true - unless he doesn't use `TContextData` anywhere else inside the loop, this call creates a single `IEnumerator` and will not be executed 40000 times.

Comment: Thanks Gobes. I had tried this but this is the error I'm recieving: {"Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown."}

Comment: @decPL I agree the `IEnumerator` will be created only once and the query will be executed only when the code will enumerate it, but so what is the difference beetween an enumeration on an `Enumerator` and an enumeration on a `List<T>`, if not the deferred execution ? I always though EF queried the database for every single line (with some query tree magic); I have had some problems about this behavior, and using a `ToList` drastically reduced the number of queries... could it be because of property navigation ?

Comment: @gobes You might be confusing deferred execution on `IEnumerable<T>` vs `IQueryable<T>`. How the latter works depends on specific implementation of that interface; can't remember how it is for EF specifically, but I'd assume it has some logic helping determine the optimal approach (if I had to guess, it's a single query and the reader is kept opened through execution). Why reading everything at once is not necessary an improvement can be seen in @AMorrisey's comment.